# Missing validation in email regex

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

So, here is my code :

```html
<p>A form with a password field that must contain 8 or more characters that are of at least one number, and one uppercase and lowercase letter:</p>

<form action="">
Password: <input type="text" name="pw" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9._%+'-\]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$" required title="Must contain at least one number and one uppercase and lowercase letter, and at least 8 or more characters">
<input type="submit">
</form>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The pattern attribute of the input tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.</p>
```

Why it is allowing

1. test.com
2. @text.com

I have added `@` with a plus to have one or more chars before it. but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Because `[A-Za-z0-9._%+'-\]+@[a-z0-9.-]` is a single character class equal to `[A-Za-z0-9._%'\][+@.-]`. Why not use `type="email"`? The title is not in sync with the pattern, BTW.

Comment: Your regex isn't doing what you think it should.

Comment: Can you post what you're expecting? Show what valid and invalid inputs look like.

Comment: @evolutionxbox what I expect is that, I want to invalidate the above 2 types of input(mentioned) in the input text.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have some restrictions to use `type="text"` :( Can you correct the above two cases.

Comment: Consider removing the backslash before the second `]`.

Comment: Try `pattern="[\w.%+'-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}"`. No ``\`` should be before `]` and you may safely remove `$` at the end to only check for the end of string once (it is done automatically).

Comment: @evolutionxbox Thanks a ton. it worked

Comment: @User985614 Do you want [to match `(`, `)`, ``\``, `[`, `/`](https://regex101.com/r/5q8LRi/5), etc. in the user name?

Comment: Are you aware that TLDs are no longer restricted to 4 chars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a problem in your pattern, you are escaping the first `]` char :

```
"[A-Za-z0-9._%+'-\]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$"
                 ^
                here
```

Escape `\` it using another `\` :  `"[A-Za-z0-9._%+'-\\]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$"` and it should work

ps : You said you cannot use `type="email"` bu you can see the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/email) of it, there is the regex used

Answer (score 1):

The issue is caused by the fact that `[A-Za-z0-9._%+'-\]+@[a-z0-9.-]` is a single character class equal to `[A-Za-z0-9._%'\][+@.-]` because you escape the `]` char ending that `[A-Za-z0-9._%+'-]` character class prematurely.

Note it is usually enough to use `type="email"` to check if the input string is email. However, since you have some restrictions to use `type="text"`, you may use

```
pattern="[\w.%+'-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}"
```

No `\` should be before `]` and you may safely remove `$` at the end to only check for the end of string once (it is done automatically by HTML5).

The final pattern HTML5 engine will apply to the input will look like `^(?:[\w.%+'-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4})$`:

- `^(?:` - start of string and a non-capturing group
- `[\w.%+'-]+` - 1 or more letters, digits, `_`, `.`, `%`, `+`, `'` or `-`
- `@` - a `@`
- `[a-z0-9.-]+` - 1 or molre lowercase ASCII letters, digits, `.` or `-`
- `\.` - a dot
- `[a-z]{2,4}` - 2, 3 or 4 lowercase ASCII letters
- `)$` - end of group and string.

Comment: Thank you so much. really helpful answer. :)